# WinForms WebView2 "file not found"

Tags: webview2

I have a VB WinForms application that I've inherited that uses the Microsoft.Web.WebView2 NuGet package (version 1.0.1774.30).  It runs fine on my dev box, but when I xcopy-deploy my app to another machine I get an unhandled exception saying little more than "file not found".  It doesn't even tell me which file is not found.

I've tracked it down to this line of code:

```
Await WebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(Nothing)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: [Distribute your app and the WebView2 Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution).

Comment: Yep, that was it.  The target machine was running Server 2016 and didn't have the runtime installed.  Thanks a lot!